# TypeORM: @JoinTable with three columns

Tags: sql, typescript, composite-primary-key, nestjs, typeorm

i got a question on typeorm and the **@JoinTable**- and **@RelationId**-Decorator. Maybe anyone can help to answer my question, give me a hint or ideally solve my problem.

I am using nestjs with typeorm to provide a private api with recipes for my family and me.

If i break down the database structure to a minimum we got three main entities:

```
recipe
- id INT(11)
- name VARCHAR(255)
# PRIMARY KEY is id
```

---

```
ingredient
- id INT(11) // not autoincrement, fetched from https://www.programmableweb.com/api/chomp
- name VARCHAR(255)
- recipeId INT(11)
# PRIMARY KEY is a composite key (id, recipeId) 
# FOREIGN KEY is recipeId on recipe
```

---

```
step
- id INT(11)
- name VARCHAR(255)
- recipeId INT(11)
# PRIMARY KEY is id
# FOREIGN KEY is recipeId on recipe
```

So, these are my three main entities for my recipes. A recipe can have multiple steps (**many**-steps-to-**one**-recipe) and a recipe can have multiple ingredients (**many**-ingredients-to-**one**-recipe)

Now the complex part. Each step **can** have a relation to one or many ingredients. This results in the following relation-table.

```
ingredient_steps_step
- ingredientId INT(11)
- stepId INT(11)
- recipeId INT(11)
# PRIMARY KEY is a composite key (ingredientId, stepId, recipeId)
# FOREIGN KEYS are ingredientId on ingredient, stepId on step, recipeId on recipe
```

---

My ingredient.entity.ts looks like this:

```ts
@ManyToMany(type => Step, step => step.ingredients)
@JoinTable({
  name: 'ingredient_steps_step',
  joinColumns: [
    {name: 'ingredientId'},
    {name: 'recipeId'},
  ],
  inverseJoinColumns: [
    {name: 'stepId'},
  ],
})
steps: Step[];

@RelationId((ingredient: Ingredient) => ingredient.steps)
stepIds: number[];

@PrimaryColumn()
recipeId: number;

@PrimaryColumn()
id: number;

@ManyToOne(type => Recipe, recipe => recipe.ingredients)
recipe: Recipe;
```

The problem is, that my ingredients table gets filled, but the relation-table (**ingredient_steps_step**) does not get filled with the entries. The problem is, that there's no decorator like **@RelationIds**, where i can provide two columns for the relation to entity *step*.

It would be great if anyone of you could help me with this. Maybe it's necessary to provide you more information about the other entities?

kind regards,

digitalhacke

Comment: Did you get the answer you were looking for? Can you post it here...

Answer (score 0):

Each relation should be in its own table. If you represent two relations in one table, you'll create duplication and might end up with inconsitencies.

#### Example

Let's assume you have a recipe MyRecipe with one step Step1 that has two ingredients. Now you want to move Step1 to another recipe OtherRecipe. Because the relation `MyRecipe <-> Step1` is represented twice (duplication) you have to change multiple entries. If you forget one, you'll end up with corrupted data.

```
ingredient_steps_step:
MyRecipe <-> Step1 <-> IngredientA
MyRecipe <-> Step1 <-> IngredientB
```

---

I would model the data as follows:

```
steps:
Step1 -> MyRecipe

step_ingredients:
Step1 <-> IngredientA
Step1 <-> IngredientB
```

This way, you don't have duplication. I'm assuming that the ingredients of a recipe are the union of the ingredients of all its steps.